# How to convert image files to tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I am trying to convert the NIH Chest X-Ray (dataset available in kaggle) images into a tensor format that is suitable for feeding into a Keras model.

```
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(

)

datagen.fit('E:/Trial chest x-ray dataset/train resized (224,224)')
```

I tried the code mentioned above but it is saying-
could not convert string to float: 'E:/Trial chest x-ray dataset/train resized (224,224)'

Then I tried flow_from_directory

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
valid_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_images,
        target_size=(224,224),
        batch_size=26,
        class_mode='categorical'
)

validation_generator=valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_images,
        target_size=(224,224),
        batch_size=26,
        class_mode='categorical'
)
```

But it is saying-
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.

Can anyone please tell me how I can convert the images into a format suitable for Keras models?

Answer (score 1):

Are these folders already created?

- train_images
- validation_images...

If you haven't already, please check this:
https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_image_retraining

Answer (score -1):

```py
image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image,tf.float32)
image = tf.image.resize(image,size = [img_size,img_size])
```